# OSX Swift - Show modal second window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to display a second window after a button click:

```
var winJ:WinJo // other window NSViewController

@IBAction func BtnNewWin(sender: AnyObject) {
    winJ = WinJo()
    winJ.showWindow(self)
}
```

This works fine but I want the new window to be modal. I accomplished this with the Xcode designer but I couldn't figure out how to do this in code.

Comment: Check out the documentation for NSApplication section named "Managing Modal Windows"

Comment: Don't you see a search box at the top-right corner of your browser window?

Comment: @El Tomato: very helpful, of course and as I said I tried to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @rocky: thanks I already looked there but couldn't figure out how to do that. As you might guess I am new to this

Comment: Exactly which part don't you understand?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks, I couldn't find the function and did not have a NSWindow and this and that. I don't think that this question was that trivial for a beginner but ok...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After I was pointed in the right direction I found the solution to my problem:

```
NSApp.runModalForWindow(winJ.window!)
```

Where NSApp is actually the instance of NSApplication.

And very important in the second window:

```
func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
        NSApp.stopModal()
    }
```

Otherwise your main window will be blocked after closing the second.